# Python - import issue, how is path entry determined?

Tags: python, python-import

I have this folder structure:

```
main_folder/
-- tests/
---- test01.py
-- some_package/
```

with the file test01.py containing the import statement

```
import some_package
```

I'm running test01.py from `main_folder`:

```
python tests/test01.py
```

so, I would expect that the working directory is `main_folder`, and that the script should see `some_package`, which is in that same folder, but I'm getting the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'node_core'
```

I tried adding these commands at the beginning of test01.py:

```
os.getcwd() -> returns main_folder
sys.path -> returns main_folder/tests
```

So, the issue is that the path entry is not what I expected (`main_folder/tests` and not `main_folder`), but why is this happening? Should this not be determined by the location from where I launch the script?

Comment: For better or worse, when you run a script with `python /path/to/script` it is `/path/to` that gets prepended to `sys.path` by default.  To make sure that your cwd is in the `sys.path`, set `PYTHONPATH` to `.`.  I suspect this was done to make it easier to have scripts with local packages that it can make use of no matter where the script is called from.

Comment: Try `python -mtests.test01` (with `main_package` as your working directory).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Not good. The test module itself should not be run as `"__main__"` script, it's the test runner's entry point itself which is main. In general `tests` subdir may not even be intended as an importable package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why what seemed to me to be the correct answer has been deleted.  So, I am posting my variation on that answer.

From the [python sys package documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html)

> - python -m module command line: prepend the current working directory.
> - python script.py command line: prepend the script’s directory. If it’s
>   a symbolic link, resolve symbolic links.
> - python -c code and python (REPL) command lines: prepend an empty
>   string, which means the current working directory

It is the second bullet that is getting you.  This is done so that one can install a script at `/path/to/script/script.py` and have it import the local some_package installed at `/path/to/script/some_package` as just `import some_package` without having to play games with having to extract `/path/to/script` from `__file__` and pushing it manually into `sys.path` in `script.py`.

There are numerous ways one could get around this problem.  Since this is a test script and unlikely to be installed somewhere else, you could add a `sys.path.insert(0,os.getcwd())`, but that would break if you ran from some directory other than `main_folder`.

You could add `sys.path.insert(0,"/path/to/main_folder")` to the script, but then you have to add this to every single test script, and update it in every location if you ever relocate `main_folder`.

A better answer is suggested by @ShadowRanger, invoke the test script as `python -m tests.test01`.  But again this only works if you are running from `main_folder`.  And somehow this just feels odd.  Maybe that's just me.

I would suggest that the best approach is to run

```
export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/main_folder
```

in any shell where you are working on this project.  Now whatever directory you run `test01.py` from.  It works.

This is basically what IDEs like PyCharm do when you mark `main_folder` as a "source directory".

Answer (score -2):

So, when you run a Python script, the current working directory isn't necessarily where the script lives. It's usually the directory from which you called the script. But Python uses a thing called sys.path to figure out where to look for modules.

In your case, running the script from the tests folder messes with this. The current working directory becomes main_folder, but sys.path still points to main_folder/tests.

To fix this, you can manually tell Python where to look. At the start of your test01.py script, add some lines to include its own directory in the places Python should look for modules:

```
import os
import sys

# Find out where this script lives
script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

# Add this script's directory to the places Python looks
sys.path.append(script_dir)

# Now Python knows where to find modules from the same directory
import some_package

# The rest of your script...
```

Absolutely! So, when you run a Python script, the current working directory isn't necessarily where the script lives. It's usually the directory from which you called the script. But Python uses a thing called sys.path to figure out where to look for modules.

In your case, running the script from the tests folder messes with this. The current working directory becomes main_folder, but sys.path still points to main_folder/tests.

To fix this, you can manually tell Python where to look. At the start of your test01.py script, add some lines to include its own directory in the places Python should look for modules:

```
import os
import sys

# Find out where this script lives
script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

# Add this script's directory to the places Python looks
sys.path.append(script_dir)

# Now Python knows where to find modules from the same directory
import some_package

# The rest of your script...
```

This way, even though you're running the script from the tests folder, Python will still find the modules in the main_folder.

Comment: The questioner has demonstrated that they know what `sys.path` is, so the tone here is a bit condecending.  Moreover, the problem isn't that he need to get the script directory into the `sys.path`.  As noted in the question the "problem" is that it IS the script directory that gets added to `sys.path`  What they want is to add the CWD to `sys.path`.